# Can the ratio test be used for determining the radius of convergence for alternating series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Usually when the ratio test is used, it is used by pitying the main term in absolute values. Although some series don't converge is their term in put in the absolute value, whereas it is convergent otherwise. For example:
$\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ (this is a power series with $x=1$).

So what should I do in case it is alternating sign series to determine it's radius of convergence?

Comment: The [alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test)?

Comment: Convergence *on* the circle of convergence has to be determined by other means from those used to determine the radius of convergence: the whole point is that the series can converge everywhere on there except one point, or nowhere, or anything in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an alternating series, $ \sum (-1)^n a_n$, where $a_n$ is a real valued sequence, we know that the sum converges if $\underset{n\to\infty}{\lim} a_n = 0$ and $ \left| a_n \right| \geq \left| a_{n+1} \right| $ via the [alternating series test.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test)

*Example:*

$$ f(x) = \sum \frac{(-1)^n}{x^n} $$ so $a_n = \frac{1}{x^n}$, which means that $f(x)$ converges if $\underset{n\to\infty}{\lim} \frac{1}{x^n} = 0$. This is true for $|x| > 1$. The next test requires that $\left|\frac{1}{x^{n+1}} \right| \leq \left| \frac{1}{x^n} \right|$, which holds for $ |x| \geq 1$.

So the interval of convergence is $ x \in (-\infty, -1)\cup (1, \infty) $